# undefined is not a function using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**edit 1** : this [page](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10258) is the problem i encounter.

**edit 2** : marked as duplicate. `$scope.currentDirectory` holds a single instance of a $resource, shorthands are only use to update the resource. therefore using isArray on a single instance breaks the symmetrical representation of the resource and the server.

---

I am trying to make a RESTful application using **angularjs** and **php**. When I request `/api/directories/[0-9]*` with `CHILDS` as the *http method* I get a json representing the directories contained in the directory targeted by the URL.

```
app.factory('Directory', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/directories/:id', {id:'@id'}, {
    childs: {
      method : 'CHILDS',
      isArray: true 
    }
})
});
```

if I write :

```
$scope.currentDirectory = Directory.get({id:1});
```

everything is great and the *currentDirectory*'s information is displayed in the view.

But then when I try to request the childs using the shorthand syntax,

```
$scope.childsOfCurrent = $scope.currentDirectory.$childs();
```

angular throws an error : **undefined is not a function**.

I tried to changed the action's properties like,

```
childs: {
      method : 'CHILDS',
      isArray: true,
      transformResponse: function () {}
}
```

of course the error is removed but `$scope.childsOfCurrent` only holds a **Promise** Object now.

Anyways if I write explicitly,

```
$scope.childsOfCurrent = Directory.childs({
  id: $scope.currentDirectory.id
});
```

it works, but i wish I could use the shorthand syntax, could someone explains why this behavior occurs ?

Comment: when defining `childs`, I'm pretty sure `method` refers to the HTTP method you want to use.  For example a `GET` or `POST`...

Comment: @DavinTryon I think this is not a problem, i tried with GET method, the problem is the same, the shorthand doesn't work here

Comment: Well, I'm fairly sure the `method` is **not** `CHILDS`.

Comment: @DavinTryon I am sure this is **not** the problem